# SQL query output on one line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Sorry, I'm not a expert in scripting,

I need to create a query in MS SQL Server to get db and db log size on one row. I am using PRTG to monitor 4 SQL servers and i need to know if there's any growth in the database and logs, eater in percentage or in bites,

I have found this new script that is perfect, it gives me all the info i need then i can set thresholds on the outputs,  the problem is PRTG can only read the info form one row, so the only info that shows up in PRTG is the database info, i also need to get the log size.

I have found this script that gives me all the info i need and i would like to send the output to one row if possible.

`USE [maccadk]
GO
SELECT 
    [TYPE] = A.TYPE_DESC
    ,[FILE_Name] = A.name
    ,[FILEGROUP_NAME] = fg.name
    ,[File_Location] = A.PHYSICAL_NAME
    ,[FILESIZE_MB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0)
    ,[USEDSPACE_MB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0 - ((SIZE/128.0) - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0))
    ,[FREESPACE_MB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0)
    ,[FREESPACE_%] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),((A.SIZE/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0)/(A.SIZE/128.0))*100)
    ,[AutoGrow] = 'By ' + CASE is_percent_growth WHEN 0 THEN CAST(growth/128 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' MB -' 
        WHEN 1 THEN CAST(growth AS VARCHAR(10)) + '% -' ELSE '' END 
        + CASE max_size WHEN 0 THEN 'DISABLED' WHEN -1 THEN ' Unrestricted' 
            ELSE ' Restricted to ' + CAST(max_size/(128*1024) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' GB' END 
        + CASE is_percent_growth WHEN 1 THEN ' [autogrowth by percent, BAD setting!]' ELSE '' END
FROM sys.database_files A LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON A.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id 
order by A.TYPE desc, A.NAME;`

[image: tables]

Thanks
Gilles

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are wanting. Do you want separate columns with information for each file, or some sort of aggregate perhaps the sizes totalled and the filenames as comma separated lists? Including an example of how you want the output formatting would be helpful.

Comment: If you need only log size info and you have one log file for the database then just add `WHERE [type] = 1` to your current query. If the conditions are incorrect then clairify your question following @DavidSpillett's comment.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin - the question says `get db AND db log size` so I assume he wants both data and log file counts. But the question remains: does he want one columns for each value or a single total. If the latter then a simple aggregate will do the job, but I'll refrain from giving that as an answer is it'll only cause confusion if it later transpires that the question is not asking for that.

Comment: Sorry i should of gave more details, I found this new script that i want to use in PRTG, i can run a query and after i can pull the info from a column name, the problem is PRTG can only pull the info from one row so i need the output to be all be sent to one row.

Answer (score 3):

Turning rows into columns known as a PIVOT operation. There are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773765/sql-server-2012-pivot-without-aggregate/15773820#15773820) to implement this operation, including a built-in expression. The simplest to understand, and most flexible, I find to be the CASE construct.

I'll use an in-line CTE to wrap your query. There's no magic here, it's just a convenient way of using your existing code. I've added column `type_desc` to help distinguish the source of each amount. The built-in function `DB_NAME()` is used to give a "key" value to the output.

```
;with YourData as
(
    select
        DBName = DB_NAME(),
        type_desc,
        [Name],
        physical_name [Path],
        CAST(size AS BIGINT)*8192 [TotalBytes], 
        CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed') AS BIGINT)*8192 [UsedBytes], 
        (case when max_size<0 
             then -1 
             else CAST(max_size AS BIGINT)*8192 end) [MaxBytes]
    from sys.database_files
)
select
    DBName,
    RowsTotalBytes = sum(case when type_desc = 'ROWS' then TotalBytes end),
    LogTotalBytes  = sum(case when type_desc = 'LOG' then TotalBytes end)
from YourData
    group by DBName;
```

The values we want occur in your query as two rows in a single column. The CASE expressions separate them into individual columns, with a NULL in the other column, still in two rows. By grouping I collapse the two rows into as single row. Hence the purpose for introducing DB_NAME().

Using SUM() serves two purposes: it returns a single value for all files of a type and ignores the NULL introduced for the other type_desc.

If you have multiple data or log files and want a separate output value for each use `Name` in the `when` instead of `type_desc`.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into this and let you know if it works out.

Comment: This did the trick for me, i can pull both values, Thanks for the help!